# Old DNS settings after 3.5 weeks

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I previously used my providers dns tool to point my domain to an AWS EC2 instance. using an A record.

After years, I decided to migrate my DNS to AWS Route53. This happened on 13 Apr 2015. Today I still see valid customer requests (in example people login in and work with my app) to the old server.

I did various tests, using dig and nslookup. It all appears to resolve well. Most online checks are valid too:

http://www.intodns.com/timeandbill.de

Today I tried another tool, which told me something about not enough nameserver were found:

http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=www.timeandbill.de

However, the domain without www works according to pingdom.

I did some additional checks and for some reason I know see a difference which I cannot explain:

```
-> dig timeandbill.de ns

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> timeandbill.de ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52827
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;timeandbill.de.            IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
timeandbill.de.     299 IN  NS  ns-1089.awsdns-08.org.
timeandbill.de.     299 IN  NS  ns-1861.awsdns-40.co.uk.
timeandbill.de.     299 IN  NS  ns-510.awsdns-63.com.
timeandbill.de.     299 IN  NS  ns-711.awsdns-24.net.

;; Query time: 200 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May  6 12:09:29 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 172
```

And the www domain:

```
➜  dig www.timeandbill.de ns

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.timeandbill.de ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16295
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.timeandbill.de.        IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
timeandbill.de.     899 IN  SOA ns-711.awsdns-24.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 56 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May  6 12:14:01 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 120
```

I assume that most of my customers use the www. domain.

The A records look ok (for me):

```
dig www.timeandbill.de

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.timeandbill.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26155
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.timeandbill.de.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.timeandbill.de. 59  IN  A   54.230.184.157
www.timeandbill.de. 59  IN  A   54.192.186.158
www.timeandbill.de. 59  IN  A   54.192.185.35
www.timeandbill.de. 59  IN  A   54.192.186.172
www.timeandbill.de. 59  IN  A   54.192.186.162
www.timeandbill.de. 59  IN  A   54.230.184.126
www.timeandbill.de. 59  IN  A   54.230.184.108
www.timeandbill.de. 59  IN  A   54.192.186.204

;; Query time: 59 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May  6 12:26:41 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 164
```

And:

```
➜  dig timeandbill.de

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> timeandbill.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18236
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;timeandbill.de.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
timeandbill.de.     59  IN  A   54.230.184.216
timeandbill.de.     59  IN  A   54.230.184.142
timeandbill.de.     59  IN  A   54.192.186.175
timeandbill.de.     59  IN  A   54.192.187.24
timeandbill.de.     59  IN  A   54.192.187.104
timeandbill.de.     59  IN  A   54.230.184.6
timeandbill.de.     59  IN  A   54.230.186.186
timeandbill.de.     59  IN  A   54.192.187.44

;; Query time: 358 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May  6 12:26:47 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 160
```

Is there an issue or why do I still get requests to the old server?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the NS record of www.timeandbill.de.
That is not the same as the NS record of timeandbill.de.

That is a specific record type you are asking for, which returns no answer as you don't have those configured.

You should query for an A or AAAA record.

So unless you want the subzone www.timeandbill.de delegated to different DNS servers there shouldn't be any NS records at www.timeandbill.de.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is it resolving to wrong addressed?

Comment: I meant, I still get requests to the old server which had an ip starting with 44 how it was defined with the old domain provider. It looks like the new DNS servers were not put into effect for some people, while other people can resolve to the new server.

Comment: Well, looking at https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.timeandbill.de it looks OK from a lot of places. Hard to say why some still hit the old IP. How long was the previous TTL? I would log the IPs and check who they are (I had this also once, but the remaining traffic was only abusive requests).

Comment: Thanks @faker. At least I have now the confirmation it's the correct settings. I already checked the incoming traffic with tshark, and it's actual user traffic. I can tell that because my app requires login, the called urls are real action requests carrying actual data.